# How to encrypt SignalR Self Hosting Hub

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to utilize the self hosted hub in **SignalR** with encryption. Specifically I don't want to allow packet sniffer to occur an see the function calls in plain text. I know there are approaches to utilize **IIS** type encryption if hosting through **IIS**, but we require a self hosted solution.

Are there any suggestions or people that have gone down this route?

Is there a way to self host an encrypted hub?

Otherwise an initial idea was to encrypt / decrypt the **JSON** object that is passing through the function calls? But you still packet sniff the function calls...

Is it possible to self host utilizing **SSL**?

How would a client connect?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to use SSL as well as groups.  No one will be able to sniff the packets unless they belong to that group.  Beyond that, encrypting json would have to be done by SignalR framework itself, which is currently not available as far as I know.